# xamarin android camera throws stop face detection failed exception

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-camera

I am starting a basic camera app using Android Intent.ActionImageCapture, StartActivityForResult() starts the camera app, but then it crashes even before capturing an image.

The Exception in logcat is java.lang.runtime Stop face detection failed.

I am not using face detection and have no need for it. And unable to handle this error.

So far this issue has occurred in 6.0.1, but works fine with versions lower and higher than 6.

This is the code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

                Java.IO.File _file = new Java.IO.File(m_cameraPhotosFolder, String.Format("mosaicfile_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

                // Tell Camera where to save image
                m_currentPhotoFileName = _file.AbsolutePath;

                intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file));

                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Logcat:

```
 V/CAM_PhotoModule( 8729): Close camera device.
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729): Stopping face detection failed, ignoring.
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729): java.lang.RuntimeException: stop face detection failed
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at android.hardware.Camera._stopFaceDetection(Native Method)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at android.hardware.Camera.stopFaceDetection(Camera.java:1751)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at com.android.camera.AndroidCameraManagerImpl$CameraHandler.stopFaceDetection(SourceFile:138)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at com.android.camera.AndroidCameraManagerImpl$CameraHandler.handleMessage(SourceFile:337)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 E/CAM_AndroidCameraManagerImpl( 8729):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
 I/MtkCam/Cam1Device(  307): (1057)(Default:0)[Cam1DeviceBase::stopPreview] +
 I/MtkCam/CamAdapter(  307): (MtkZsd)[BaseCamAdapter::onImgBufProviderDestroyed] id=4, ImgBufProvider=0x0
 W/MtkCam/CamClient/FDClient(  307): (1057)[stopFaceDetection] FD was not running
 I/MtkCam/CamAdapter(  307): (MtkZsd)[BaseCamAdapter::onImgBufProviderDestroyed] id=5, ImgBufProvider=0x0
 W/MtkCam/CamClient/OTClient(  307): (1057)[stopOT] OT was not running
 I/MtkCam/Cam1Device(  307): (1057)(Default:0)[Cam1DeviceBase::stopPreview] -
 I/MtkCam/DisplayClient(  307): [uninit] + getStrongCount(2)
 I/MtkCam/CamAdapter(  307): (MtkZsd)[BaseCamAdapter::onImgBufProviderDestroyed] id=1, ImgBufProvider=0xd9eaba90
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, have you tried to change a device for testing? I didn't find any problem with your code.

Comment: this issue currently is only on Wiley Fox (sdk 6.0.1) device, i am not able to reproduce on other device. No idea if this is issue is only related to this device.
I'd have to wait for crash reports to see if someone else having same problem.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT It's worth pointing out that the Wileyfox uses cyanogenMod, which might be the source of the problem

Comment: The app just crashes and does not even show option to report crash.